# Bug when converting "synthetic points" example from Openlayers 3.5 to 3.16

Tags: openlayers-3

Trying to update the example at http://ol3.qtibia.ro/build/examples/synthetic-points.html

to the latest version of Openlayers. Getting a bug I can't figure out; triggered by the pointermove event, as a consequence of the displaySnap function. Play around with the JS fiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/1vzp3mwd/7/

```
var point = null;
var line = null;
var displaySnap = function(coordinate) {
  var closestFeature = vectorSource.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(coordinate);
  if (closestFeature === null) {
    point = null;
    line = null;
  } else {
    var geometry = closestFeature.getGeometry();
    var closestPoint = geometry.getClosestPoint(coordinate);
    if (point === null) {
      point = new ol.geom.Point(closestPoint);
    } else {
      point.setCoordinates(closestPoint);
    }
    if (line === null) {
      line = new ol.geom.LineString([coordinate, closestPoint]);
    } else {
      line.setCoordinates([coordinate, closestPoint]);
    }
  }
  map.render();
};

map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
  if (evt.dragging) {
    return;
  }
  var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
  displaySnap(coordinate);
});

map.on('click', function(evt) {
  displaySnap(evt.coordinate);
});

var imageStyle = new ol.style.Circle({
  radius: 10,
  fill: null,
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'rgba(255,255,0,0.9)',
    width: 3
  })
});
var strokeStyle = new ol.style.Stroke({
  color: 'rgba(255,255,0,0.9)',
  width: 3
});
map.on('postcompose', function(evt) {
  var vectorContext = evt.vectorContext;
  if (point !== null) {
    vectorContext.setStyle(imageStyle);
    vectorContext.drawGeometry(point);
  }
  if (line !== null) {
    vectorContext.setStyle(null, strokeStyle);
    vectorContext.drawGeometry(line);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated, working example: http://jsfiddle.net/1vzp3mwd/8/

Here's what I did:

- I loaded the ["debug" version](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.16.0/ol-debug.js) of the full library to make for nicer stack traces and easier debugging.  (Note that you would never want to use this in production.)
- I changed your `vectorContext.setStyle()` calls so that they were called with an `ol.style.Style` object.  See [the API docs](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.render.canvas.Immediate.html#setStyle) for more detail.

Here is the relevant part of the updated example:

```js
var stroke = new ol.style.Stroke({
  color: 'rgba(255,255,0,0.9)',
  width: 3
});

var style = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Circle({
    radius: 10,
    fill: null,
    stroke: stroke
  }),
  stroke: stroke
});

map.on('postcompose', function(evt) {
  var vectorContext = evt.vectorContext;
  vectorContext.setStyle(style);
  if (point !== null) {
    vectorContext.drawGeometry(point);
  }
  if (line !== null) {
    vectorContext.drawGeometry(line);
  }
});
```

Make sure to use http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/ when looking for examples (this will give you examples for the latest release).  You can always get to that from http://openlayers.org/.  The Synthetic Points example you are trying to reproduce is located here: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/synthetic-points.html.

Comment: Thanks for the update @tim-schaub. Is there a way we can get Google to invalidate searches to old examples. I've been struggling with finding the latest examples without knowing about http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/ 

I suspect that is a common problem for n00bs trying to use Openlayers. I'll check out the latest and greatest.

Comment: Having the old examples in search results is a hassle.  We've added a `robots.txt` to discourage bots from crawling these.  You can see the result in a search like https://www.google.com/search?q=openlayers+synthetic+points.  Although the first result is for a 3.2 example, I see "A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt" there.  In addition, if you follow a link to one of the old examples, you should see a notice about the example using an outdated version with a link to the latest.  These measures are relatively recent - things should improve over time.